# Why does wp_enqueue_style doesn't work here?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, styles

I'm developing a theme on WordPress. My index.php and style.css are in the same folder, at the root of the theme directory. My css files are in a "css" folder, my js files are in "js" folder. I want to add the CSS and JS to the index ( with the wp enqueue style/script ) in the functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_stylesheet' );
function add_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_register_style('plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins.css');
    wp_register_style('nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/navigation-menu.css');
    wp_register_style('shortcode', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shortcodes.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
    wp_enqueue_style('plugins');
    wp_enqueue_style('nav');
    wp_enqueue_style('shortcode');
}
```

But that doesn't work.
I tried with a 'if' condition, I tried with just the wp_enqueue_style function ( and many other solutions I found on google ), but none of these work. I have no idea what the problem is.

Here's a screenshot of the [file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQSLT.png)

Edit : It doesn't work as in the css is not linked to the php files, it shows plain HTML text. If I open the dev tools, it shows no CSS properties.

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm2SO.png)

Thanks !

Comment: check what does `wp_register_style` return?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how can wp_register_style actually return something ?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "none of these work"? Is the wrong path outputted in your markup? Is there any error message, either thrown by WP itself or your browser's console? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I edited the post, basically it just shows plain text ( added a screenshot of what is displayed )

Comment: @MaelLandrin, wp_register_style  returns true of false.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between wp_enqueue_* and respective wp_register_* functions, is that the first adds scripts/styles to the queue and the second prepares scripts/styles to be added.

You need to move the add action after the function and it'll work:

```
function add_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_register_style('plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins.css');
    wp_register_style('nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/navigation-menu.css');
    wp_register_style('shortcode', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shortcodes.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
    wp_enqueue_style('plugins');
    wp_enqueue_style('nav');
    wp_enqueue_style('shortcode');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_stylesheet' );
```

**Updated answer below:**

Why not just enqueue the styles instead of registering and then enqueuing them, like this:

```
function theme_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
```

wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . 'wp_enqueue_style('plugins', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');');

```
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```